# Angular ng-show not correct when loading the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have the following checkboxes generated with AngularJS on my html page:

```
<div ng-controller="MirrorCheckboxController">
    <div ng-repeat="setting in settings">
        <input type="checkbox" 
               ng-attr-id="{{ setting.id }}"
               ng-model="checkedElements[setting.id]"
               ng-click="callSaveFunction(setting.id)"> 

        <label ng-attr-for="{{ setting.id }}">
            <span class="checkbox">{{setting.name}}</span>
        </label> 
    </div>                  
</div>

<div ng-show="showEvents(checkedElements)" id="events">
      ...show something
</div>
```

If the last checkbox (Weather) is checked, the DIV with the ID "events" should be shown. This actually already works fine, I just have the problem that if I load the page and Weather is already true from the storage, the "DIV" events container doesn't show up. So I would need something to check that when loading the page and that works fine and doesn't get in the way of ng-show

My controller is:

```
exampleApp.controller('MirrorCheckboxController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    $scope.checkedElements = {};

    $scope.settings = [{
        name: 'Weather',
        value: '',
        id: 'mirror-1'
    }, {
        name: 'Date and Clock',
        value: '',
        id: 'mirror-2'
    }, {
        name: 'Traffic Situation',
        value: '',
        id: 'mirror-3'
    }, {
        name: 'Personal Calendar',
        value: '',
        id: 'mirror-4'
    }];

    // the method to display or hide the event container
    $scope.showEvents = function(obj) {
        return (obj['mirror-4']);
    };
}]);
```

The storage works fine as well and the checkbox is also checked onload. Is there a possibility to use something else at the same time as ng-show just to catch that case when loading the page? I'm struggling with that for a while and tried some JQuery solutions, but nothing worked.

edit:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // wait until bus service is available
    window.name = 'NG_DEFER_BOOTSTRAP!';
    window["Client"] = {
        SID: "{{SID}}",
        throwErrorOnBootFailure: true,
        readyCallback: function () {
            (function() {
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    angular.resumeBootstrap([]);
                });
            })();
            //load current checkbox states from the storage API while loading
            loadMirror_WeatherEnabler();
        }
    };
</script>

  <!-- Model API dependencies -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/hcc/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/bus/ModelAPICommunicationObject.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/bus/ModelAPI.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/bus/ModelAPIWebsocketClientFactory.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/bus/bus-client-bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Comment: what storage? Nothing shown will update `checkedElements ` when controller initializes. Create a plunker that reproduces issue

Comment: I'm using the storage API of a Java middleware, so I can't reproduce the issue. However, on loading the page I print the current state of my checkbox in the logs - so storing and reading the state is working for sure. Even though the state is logged as true when initializing, ng-show doesn't show the div.

Comment: but that is on server...you need that data passed to client and are not showing anything related to it in the question

Comment: I extended my code: onclick of the checkbox, callSaveFunction will save the state in the storage API, and loadMirror_WeatherEnabler loads the state from the sorage